# border collapse for div not working

Tags: html, css

I am below css and html for creating bay design using div.
   In HTML I have try `display: table` and `display : table-cell`. But I am not getting result.

```css
.bay-wrapper{ 
  display: table; 
  width:10%; 
  height:auto; 
  float:left; 
  background:#fff; 
  text-align:center;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.bay-cell-full{
    display: table-cell;
    border:1px solid #000;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.bay-cell{
    display: table-cell;
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="bay-wrapper">
   <div class="bay-cell-full">Bay 20</div>
   <div class="bay-cell">1</div>
   <div class="bay-cell">7</div>
   <div class="bay-cell">2</div>
   <div class="bay-cell">8</div>
   <div class="bay-cell">3</div>
   <div class="bay-cell">9</div>
   <div class="bay-cell">4</div>
   <div class="bay-cell">10</div>
   <div class="bay-cell">5</div>
   <div class="bay-cell">11</div>
   <div class="bay-cell">6</div>
   <div class="bay-cell">12</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Borders are collapsed into a single border in your example (border-spacing and empty-cells properties will be ignored).

The line

```
border-collapse:collapse;
```

it is ok. Are you sure this is the effect you want to obtain?

https://jsfiddle.net/MadalinaTn/bthrbqxz/

[image]

Comment: Yes effect is correct. But border is not collapse. I used the border-collapse:collapse. but its not working.